# How to understand makefiles and python

Tags: python, makefile

I'm trying to understand how a makefile works for compiling some .ui files to .py (PyQt -> Python). This is the makefile that I am using that was autogenerated:

```
# Makefile for a PyQGIS plugin 
UI_FILES = Ui_UrbanAnalysis.py

RESOURCE_FILES = resources.py

default: compile
    compile: $(UI_FILES) $(RESOURCE_FILES)

%.py : %.qrc
    pyrcc4 -o $@  $<

%.py : %.ui
    pyuic4 -o $@ $<
```

When I type:

```
$ make
```

I get the following message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `compile', needed by `default'.  Stop.
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know the build steps you are trying to achieve, but both of these lines:

```
default: compile
    compile: $(UI_FILES) $(RESOURCE_FILES)
```

look like target lines, so they should probably be:

```
default: compile

compile: $(UI_FILES) $(RESOURCE_FILES)
```

As it was make is probably trying to interpret the `compile:...` line as an action which won't do anything *and* means that there is no `compile` target.

---

One more thing, you might want to use

```
PHONY: default compile
```

to tell make that these are abstract targets and do not represent files. Just as a matter of good practice.

Comment: Yes!  The OP needs to be very careful about whitespace in makefiles - for some versions of make, even a tab on its own on the line below a target line can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks - that solved the problem. What do you mean by 'abstract targets' ? I'm just starting to understand how makefiles work so I'm not familiar with the terminology

Comment: @celenius: Consider `make clean`. There is no file called "clean" and no expectation that there will be one. That is an abstract target. Contrast that with `make resources.py`, in which make will check to see if the *file* "resources.py" exists is newer than all of it's dependencies and if not, attempt to (re)create that *file*.